# Is 33 the minimum skill check result for a multiclassed 11 rogue/9 artificer using Reliable Talent, Expertise, Guidance, and Flash of Genius?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, multi-classing, rogue, artificer

1. Any proficient ability check d20 roll of lower than 10 is set to 10 with the Reliable Talent rogue feature.
2. +17 from the Expertise rogue feature (12 + ability modifier of +5).
3. +a minimum of 1 from the *guidance* cantrip.
4. +5 from the Flash of Genius artificer feature with 20 Int:

   > Flash of Genius
   >
   > Starting at 7th level, you gain the ability to come up with solutions under pressure. When you or another creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an ability check or a saving throw, you can use your reaction to add your Intelligence modifier to the Roll.
   >
   > You can use this feature a number of times equal to your Intelligence modifier (minimum of once). You regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

= 33? Am I stacking these right?

Comment: Given some of the answers that have come in, it may be worth emphasising that you are not looking for an optimization, but a check on feature stacking. The title can be interpreted to be a char-opt start.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Yes

You've done all the math and that's correct. Of course, you need to be using a skill check in which you're proficient, but you are a 20th level PC and built it in such a way to maximize the skill check possibilities.